# Azure App Service plugin for Visual Studio Code does not see my subscription

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have created an Azure subscription and I can see the subscription ID in my account on the https://portal.azure.com/ website.

When I click on the Azure App Service icon in Visual Studio Code and click Select Subscription I do not see my subscription but the one of a client.

I'm logged in with the right email address for that account in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1):

Took me some time to figure out that I have two accounts on the same address. I logged out of Azure App Service and logged back in but when to the other account.

[image]